# How to make Teams remember my password?

Tags: 20.04, password, microsoft-teams

I have to use Teams at work.

Every day when I start my machine Teams start automatically but the password is not remembered.

Is there a way to save the password and not have to enter it when Teams is starting up?

My version of Ubuntu is:

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

My version of Teams is:

```
Microsoft Teams Version 1.3.00.30857 (64-bit).
```

Comment: If your employer uses the Azure Active Directory system for authentication, then an administrator may have explicitly blocked the ability to save the password as a security precaution (or for corporate compliance reasons). There is nothing that I've seen that prevents Teams from remembering my password, and I use it daily as well 